# Open a .msg file with Outlook 2016?

Tags: powershell

How do I open a .msg file with Outlook 2016, with a Powershell script?

Tried the following, nothing occurred - no errors:

```
Invoke-Item "L:\PAM\Day1.msg"

$Filepath = "L:\PAM\Day1.msg"
```

Comment: As for the 2nd command: `$FilePath = "..."` is just a variable assignment from a string - you shouldn't expect it to execute anything.

Comment: What does `cmd /c assoc .msg` return?

Comment: .msg=Outlook.File.msg.15

Comment: Should the `15` be `16`?

Comment: Unless you think that can be an issue - then Ill get it changed, but Outlook is working fine

Comment: Outlook working fine is unrelated to file associations. You need to investigate whether file type `Outlook.File.msg.15` points to your Outlook 2016 executable or not. As an aside: if you want a user in a comment exchange to be actively notified of responses, you must `@`-notify them; in this case: `@mklement0`.

Comment: Why do you want to open a file?  This may seem like a sarcastic question, but it's not.  You might want to open a new file in order to put something in it.  You might want to open an existing file in order to display the contents.  Or you might want to copy the contents to a variable in order to process them. Help us to help you.

Comment: @WalterMitty - It is just opening the .msg file with Outlook, that is it. The user will then email that template after completing the script, there is no additional steps to this other than simply opening the file in Outlook 2016 after the script is completed - pretty "simple"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a resolution myself - pretty simple

```
Start-Process -FilePath "L:\PAM\Day1.msg"
```